# Converting CSV to JSON using PHP

Tags: php, json, laravel, csv, data-conversion

I am writing a Lumen app and have a CSV file that I need to convert to JSON.

```
"ALL","13","5","4","4", "TEST01","3","1","0","2",
```

I want to convert it to a JSON file like so.

```
{
    "ALL": {
        "Total": 13,
        "In Use":5,
        "Available": 4,
        "Asleep": 4
     },
     "TEST01": {
        "Total": 3,
        "In Use":1,
        "Available": 0,
        "Asleep": 2
     }
}
```

How could I go about doing this using PHP or a Laravel/Lumen native way?

Comment: You would write some code to do it. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Will it always be in the same format? 

{ 
    "key": { 
    "Total" : a,
    "In Use": b,
    "Avaliable": c,
    "Asleep": d
    },
    .......
}

?

Answer (score 1):

1. parse CSV to array, using [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)
2. arrange items in array according to your output format.
3. output JSON string with [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)